# Conditional Independence property

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

Hello in one class my instructor once gave us a sketch proof that involves the following equality regarding conditional independence:
$$
P \perp B \mid C \quad \land  \quad A \perp B \mid (C \cup P) \quad \implies \quad (A \cup P) \perp B \mid C
$$
where $\perp$ indicates independence and $C$ and $P$ are disjoint.
I cannot remember all the details but I believe $A$ and $P$ are not disjoint.

Is this equality true? I tried to prove it by showing $p(a, p, b \mid c) = p(a, p \mid c) p(b \mid c)$ but could not proceed further since I do not know how to incorporate $A \perp B \mid (C \cup P)$.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: That seems unlikely to be true in general: I would worry in particular about $(C \cup P)$

Comment: @Henry Yes I also found it difficult to prove. I forgot to mention that $C$ and $P$ are disjoint.

Comment: If $P$ and $C$ are disjoint events then $\mathbb P(P \mid C)=0$